# Is it possible to extract data from ContourPlot?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot the contours of specific eigenvalue for a big matrix which can be done numerically. Once I get the contours, is it possible to extract the data as a list for example `{x,y}`. here is the code where I evaluated the contours (as a function of `x` and `y`) of specific eigenvalue `λ`

```
M1 = {{0, I Sin[x] + Sin[y], 
    3 - Cos[x] - Cos[y], -1}, {-I Sin[x] + Sin[y], 0, -1, 
    3 - Cos[x] - Cos[y]}, {3 - Cos[x] - Cos[y], -1, 
    0, -I Sin[x] - Sin[y]}, {-1, 3 - Cos[x] - Cos[y], 
    I Sin[x] - Sin[y], 0}};

tc = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0, 0}};

Mn[n_] := 
 SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}, {4 n, 4 n}] -> {M1}, 
   Band[{1, 5}, {4 n, 4 n}] -> {tc}, 
   Band[{5, 1}, {4 n, 4 n}] -> {ConjugateTranspose[tc]}}]

w = 40; En = 4 w;(*w must be>1*)

MM[x_, y_] = Mn[w];
f[\[Lambda]_?NumericQ, {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}] := 
 Det[MM[x, y] - \[Lambda]*IdentityMatrix[En]]


With[{\[Lambda] = 0.4}, 
 ContourPlot[f[\[Lambda], {x, y}] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 20]]
```

[image]

Now, I would like to obtain the eigenvectors of the eigenvalue `λ` for all `{x,y}` on the contour. For this I would like to extract the the values of `{x, y}` from the contour and then use `Eigensystem[Mn[w]]` to find eigenvectors associated with each single point `{x,y}`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update** Extract line segments

```
lineSegments = lines /. Line[{min_, ___, max_}] :> points[[1, min ;; max]]
```

Plot as individual lines

```
ListLinePlot@lineSegments
```

[image]

Or combined using `Show`

```
ListLinePlot /@ lineSegments // Show[#, PlotRange -> All] &
```

[image]

---

You can extract the points using

```
plot = With[{λ = 0.4}, 
  ContourPlot[f[λ, {x, y}] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 20]]

points = plot // Cases[#, GraphicsComplex[points_, ___] :> points, Infinity] &
```

Verify by plotting the points

```
points // ListPlot
```

[image]

The lines drawn on the contour plot are described by

```
lines = Cases[plot, _Line, Infinity]
```

The list argument to `Line` contains the index of the point in `points`.

Comment: Thanks @Rohit Namjoshi! Just one more thing, may you please help me to manipulate the points such that I can use `ListLinePlot[points] `  instead of `ListPlot[points]` ?

Comment: @HD2006 Updated to show extraction and plotting of the line segments.

Comment: @ Rohit Namjoshi, Thanks for the help, that is cool,  is it possible to connect those segments to get each circle as one segment? for simplicity, you can set `w=20`. I tried to do that using  `Sort` but could not succeed.

Comment: ,I also tried to use `Interpolation` with the obtained data to generate a function of `{x,y}` and then I can use `ListLinePlot` or generate more clean date using the new function, any idea please how this can be done?

Comment: @HD2006 The problem is that there can be several line segments for a single contour and that they are not necessarily connected. One thing to try is to extract the first point from a segment and find the segment with the [Nearest](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html) last point. Join them to form a new segment and repeat. Use `Interpolation` to fill in the gaps. This might work well for the inner contours but not for the outer ones. I don't have time to try that now, maybe you can experiment with that approach.

Comment: Thanks for your time, you helped  a lot. I will try that approach otherwise I will post a new question:-)