# Find the parameter in NDSolve giving the desired solution

Tags: differential-equations, fitting, nonlinear, parameters

**EDIT**: I've edited many times because the system gives errors when the body is modified all at once.
I've simplified the problem. The simplification consists of having reduced the number of parameters from 2 to 1.

I find myselef in choosing by hand the right parameter that let `ParametricNDSolve`  return the desidered solution. I'm sure there is an easy alternative, but I can't find it anywhere. I thank anyone who can help.

I have a two ODEs system depending on 1 parameter $k$. Thanks to `ParametricNDSolve` I get the desidered family of solutions $h[k](x)$ and $v[k](x)$, as expected. Furthermore, I know (from books) that the solution $v[k]$ behaves at large $x$ like
$v[k](x)\sim \frac{A_{k}}{x}+\frac{B_{k}}{x^2}$, so I can fit the tail of the function $v[k]$ using `NonlinearModelFit` for any given value of $k$.
I'm eventually interested in finding the value of the parameter $k$ with the particular property that the fit gives $A_{k}=0$ and $B_{k}\neq 0$. How can this be done?

For now I found by hand that the value $k=7.94$ kinda works, but an automated method would be much better. Here is the code:

```
rh = 1
rhb = rh*(1 + 0.01)
q = 2
m = -2
mu = 31

system = {
  f'[x] == g[x], 
  g'[x] == -2 g[x]/x + 
    2*(q^2)*f[x]*v[x]^2/(x^2 - ((rh)^3)/x),
  v'[x] == a[x],
  a'[x] == -((2 x + ((rh)^3)/x^2)/(x^2 - ((rh)^3)/x))*a[x] - 2*a[x]/x - (q^2)*(f[x]/(x^2 - ((rh)^3)/x))^2*v[x] + (m/(x^2 -(rh)^3/x))*v[x],
  (*initial conditions below*)
  f[rhb] == 0 , 
  f[100000000] == mu, 
  v[rhb] == k, 
  a[rhb] == ((m)/(3*rh))*(k)}; 
sol = ParametricNDSolve[system, {f, v}, {x, rhb, 1000000}, {k}];

datascalar[k_] = 
  Table[{i, Evaluate[v[k][x] /. sol] /. x -> i}, {i, 200, 100000}];
nlmscalar[k_] = NonlinearModelFit[datascalar[k], A/x + B/x^2, {A, B}, x]
```

As can be read from the last line of the code, I can make a fit for every value of $k$! For example if I choose $k=7.94$ (found by hand) i get

```
nlmscalar[7.94]["BestFitParameters"]
{B -> 203.147, A -> -0.00218232}
```

and $A$ is "close" to zero, but it's not zero. I just need an algorithm that finds the value of $k$ for which the fit gives `A -> 0.`. This value is supposed to be near $7.94$. Said otherwise, I want the code to vary $k$ until the fit gives  `{B -> "whatever it is", A -> 0.}`.

Comment: We can solve it as a minimization problem - see my answer.

Comment: Did you remove boundary condition f'[rhb] == e while I used it in my answer? Also I see that you add new boundary condition f[100000000] == mu, and therefore we have new problem. This problem also has solution with NMinimize

Comment: Sorry I didn't read this comment. Yes, I slightly modified the code. I fixed the bc f[100000000]==mu (actually this should have been $f(\infty)=\mu$, physically amounting to fix the chemical potential to \mu). I'm still doing things by hand and the results I'm getting are fine. However, an automated method is still lacking.

Comment: My last attempt was to extrapolate the parameter $A$ from the fit as `myA[k_] := A /. nlmscalar[k]["BestFitParameters"]`, and then minimize `NMinimize[ Abs[myA[k]],k]` but the last step doesn't work.

Comment: Is your equations taken from https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.3295.pdf ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `NMinimize` to fit parameters as follows

```
rh = 1;
rhb = rh*(1 + 0.01);
q = 2;
m = -2;
mu = 31;

system = {f'[x] == g[x], 
   g'[x] == -2 g[x]/x + 2*(q^2)*f[x]*v[x]^2/(x^2 - ((rh)^3)/x), 
   v'[x] == a[x], 
   a'[x] == -((2 x + ((rh)^3)/x^2)/(x^2 - ((rh)^3)/x))*a[x] - 
     2*a[x]/x - (q^2)*(f[x]/(x^2 - ((rh)^3)/x))^2*
      v[x] + (m/(x^2 - (rh)^3/x))*v[x],(*initial conditions below*)
   f[rhb] == 0, g[rhb] == e, v[rhb] == k, a[rhb] == ((m)/(3*rh))*(k)};
sol = ParametricNDSolve[system, {f, v}, {x, rhb, 10000}, {k, e}];
solm = 
 NMinimize[{Norm[
    Table[A/x + B/x^2 - Evaluate[v[k, e][x] /. sol] /. x -> i, {i, 
      200, 10000, 100}]], {k > 0, e > 0, A < 0, B > 0}}, {k, e, A, B}]

(*Out[]= {1.72976*10^-8, {k -> 0.310498, e -> 2.41152, A -> -0.12763, 
  B -> 0.796307}}*)
```

Note, this solution is differ from the hand made `k=2,e=8` and also more precise. Visualization

```
p = {k, e} /. 
  solm[[2]]; Plot[{v[p[[1]], p[[2]]][x] /. sol, (A/x + B/x^2) /. 
   solm[[2]]}, {x, 200, 10000}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> {"NDSolve", "NMinimize"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Update 1. Let consider system of equations (6)-(7) from the paper [Building an AdS/CFT superconductor](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3295v1). This system we transfer in to new one by introducing two functions $\Psi =u(y), \Phi =v(y)$ and mapping interval $(1,\infty)$ to $(0,1)$ with $y=1/r$, we have

```
sys={(2 u[y])/(1/y^2 - m y) + (v[y]^2 u[y])/(1/y^2 - m y)^2 + 
   2 y^3 Derivative[1][u][y] - 
   y^2 (2 y + (2/y + m y^2)/(1/y^2 - m y)) Derivative[1][u][y] + 
   y^4 (u^\[Prime]\[Prime])[y] == 
  0, -((2 v[y] u[y]^2)/(1/y^2 - m y)) + y^4 (v^\[Prime]\[Prime])[y] ==
   0}
```

Note, in this model the Hawking temperature of the black hole is $T=\frac{3 m^{1/3}}{4 \pi L^{4/3}}$, where $L=1$ is the AdS radius, and we put $m=1$ as well. Boundary conditions for this system we put as follows

```
bc1 = {v[y] == 0, u[y] == 3 y0 u'[y]/2} /. 
  y -> y0; bc0 = { v[y] == mu - y rho, u[y] == A y + B y^2} /. y -> 0;
```

We are looking for some solutions with $A=0$. To solve this problem numerically we introduce new boundary conditions with two parameters $p_1=v'(1),p_2=u(1)$, then we normalize $v/p_1,u/p_2$, finally we have parametric function in the form

```
eps = $MachineEpsilon; y0 = 1 - 10^-6; m = 1; 
sol[p1_, p2_] := 
 NDSolve[{(2 u[y])/(1/y^2 - m y) + (
     p1^2 v[y]^2 u[y])/(1/y^2 - m y)^2 + 2 y^3 Derivative[1][u][y] - 
     y^2 (2 y + (2/y + m y^2)/(1/y^2 - m y)) Derivative[1][u][y] + 
     y^4 (u^\[Prime]\[Prime])[y] == 
    0, -((2  p2^2 v[y] u[y]^2)/(1/y^2 - m y)) + 
     y^4 (v^\[Prime]\[Prime])[y] == 0, v[y0] == 0, v'[y0] == 1, 
   u[y0] == 1, u'[y0] == 2/3/y0}, {u, v}, {y, eps, y0}]
```

We can plot function `u'[0.]` to visualize region where $A=0$

```
Plot3D[u'[eps] /. sol[p1, p2][[1]], {p1, 0.1, 5}, {p2, 0.1, 5}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
 Boxed -> False, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", PlotPoints -> 50, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Using `ContourPlot` we can retrieve data with `A=0`(see this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219371/is-it-possible-to-extract-data-from-contourplot))

```
plot=ContourPlot[(Evaluate[u'[eps] /. sol[p1, p2][[1]]]) == 0, {p1, 0.1, 
   5}, {p2, .1, 5}] // Quiet

points = plot // 
  Cases[#, GraphicsComplex[points_, ___] :> points, Infinity] &
```

[image: Figure 3]

Update 2. In a case of original system we have

```
sys = {f'[x] == g[x], 
  g'[x] == -2 g[x]/x + 2*(q^2)*k^2 *f[x]*v[x]^2/(x^2 - ((rh)^3)/x), 
  v'[x] == a[x], 
  a'[x] == -((2 x + ((rh)^3)/x^2)/(x^2 - ((rh)^3)/x))*a[x] - 
    2*a[x]/x - (q^2)*g0^2 (f[x]/(x^2 - ((rh)^3)/x))^2*
     v[x] + (m/(x^2 - (rh)^3/x))*v[x]}; bc2 = {f[rhb] == 0, 
  g[rhb] == 1, v[rhb] == 1, a[rhb] == ((m)/(3*rh))*(1)};

sol2[p1_, p2_] := 
 NDSolve[{sys, bc2} /. {q -> 2, m -> -2, rh -> 1, rhb -> 11/10, 
    k -> p1, g0 -> p2}, {f, g, v, a}, {x, 11/10, 10}]

s2 = sol2[1, 1][[1]]
```

We map this system on the unit interval with using `y=1/x` as follows

```
eq = {-y^2 Derivative[1][f][y] == 
    g[y], -y^2 Derivative[1][g][y] == -2 y g[y] + (
     2 q^2  k^2 f[y] v[y]^2)/(
     1/y^2 - rh^3 y), -y^2 Derivative[1][v][y] == 
    a[y], -y^2 Derivative[1][a][
      y] == -2 y a[y] - ((2/y + rh^3 y^2) a[y])/(1/y^2 - rh^3 y) + (
     m v[y])/(1/y^2 - rh^3 y) - (
     q^2 g0^2 f[y]^2 v[y])/(1/y^2 - rh^3 y)^2};
bc1 = {f[rhb] == 0, g[rhb] == 1, v[rhb] == 1, 
   a[rhb] == ((m)/(3*rh))*(1)};
par = {q -> 2, m -> -2, rh -> 1, rhb -> 10/11};

eps = $MachineEpsilon; 
sol[p1_, p2_] := 
 NDSolve[{eq, bc1} /. {q -> 2, m -> -2, rh -> 1, rhb -> 10/11, 
    k -> p1, g0 -> p2}, {f, g, v, a}, {y, eps, 10/11}]

s1 = sol[1, 1][[1]]
```

We can compare two numerical solutions in one point, for example, at `p1=1,p2=1,x=1/y=3` and have got same results

```
{f[x], g[x], v[x], a[x]} /. s2 /. x -> 3

(*Out[]= {1.51741, 0.624487, 0.384472, -0.166605}*)

{f[x], g[x], v[x], a[x]} /. s1 /. x -> 1/3

(*Out[]= {1.51741, 0.624487, 0.384472, -0.166605}*)
```

Then we compute function `v'[0.]` to visualize region where `A=0`

```
ContourPlot[(Evaluate[v'[eps] /. sol[p1, p2][[1]]]) == 0, {p1, 0.01, 
   1.5}, {p2, .01, 1.5}] // Quiet
```

[image: Figure 4]

This picture shows chaotic behavior of the numerical solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I think there is misunderstanding here. Does this code find A,B,k,e giving the best match between the (tail of the) solution and the function A/x+B/x^2, right? This is not exactly what I need.
Maybe I can rephrase my problem as follows: I want to get A=0 from the fit of the solution. What parameters k,e should I put in the ODEs?

Comment: Have you any constraints for k, e? Are they real, rational or integer? How do you explain your choice  k=2,e=8?

Comment: 1. It was not a choice, just found values for k,e that (almost) do the job.
2. No, they are not supposed to be integers; point is that in doing things by hand I started looking for integers.
3. k can be taken >0.

However, I've simplified the problem by changing one initial condition, precisely the second one in the code (turned out this is ok for my purposes). Now there is only k to be determined. The choice of the updated initial condition suggests that the value of k I'm looking for lies near 7.94. I've edited my question, I hope it's clearer now. 
Thanks again for help.

Comment: Ok! I made quick research and found out, that $f=c_1/x+c_2/x^2+..., v=a_3/x^3+..., $ at $x\rightarrow \infty$.  How did you get your asymptotic $v=A/x+B/x^2+...$?

Comment: I give some of my references from arXiv: 

[link1](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3295) formula (8) and

[link2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6693) formula (9,10) with $d=4$ and $m^2L^2=-2$ (it's a common choice of the parametrs of the original physical problem, I used the same).

Alternatively, one can just consider huge values of $x$ and neglecting $O(x^{-4})$ terms, the ODE is $v''+4v'/x+2v/{x^2}$, whose solution is the one I've used.

Regardin $f$,  this is supposed to behave like $\mu-\rho/x$ (same references), but this shouldn't be important I think.

Comment: Thank you for the papers sited, but they used 2 boundary conditions  (bc) only  at `x=rhb` while you use 4 bc. With 2 bc at the horizon they need to put some bc at $x\rightarrow \infty$, while you try to optimize `k, e` for desired solution at $x\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Yes,  excactly, you are right! I'm trying to do the "reverse" procedure: optimizing the 4 bc at  `x=rhb` aiming to get the desired solution at $x\to \infty$. This resemble a shooting method. This because I didn't find any sensible way to impose the bc at infinity .

Comment: Thank you very much for your last answer. You definitely got the point. 
I've read the code carefully and did all the calculations and everything seems fine to me. Unfortunately, the code is not working for me because of an error in the NDSolve. It starts as `"Tag List in {f->ParametricFunction[1,Internal`Bag[<1>]` and it ends as `v-><<18>>[<<1>>]}[p1_,p2_] is Protected.`. I'll try to spot the error, maybe I'm doing something wrong. However, I'll mark this as definitive answer.

Comment: @GianluigiTartaglione Please, see Update 2 to my answer.